# Calculate how long user stop at indicator position on a website

Tags: algorithm

I want to detect attention of users on a website. And I've data includes:

1. The scroll positions array (from top = 0): `[982,1023,1125,1191,1193,1196,1228,1288,1359,1428,1476,1509,1511,1541,1625,1731,1814,1871,1882,1855,1812,1750,1661,1582,1564,1561,1504,1390,1281,1246,1216,1135,1043,985,981]`
2. The time array in millisecond: (corresponding to scroll positions array): 
   `[2514,2588,2687,2789,2883,3410,3490,3590,3691,3794,3890,3992,4083,4591,4692,4795,4894,4990,5082,8382,8482,8592,8691,8790,8882,9190,9291,9392,9489,9590,10090,10188,10289,10392,10482]`

That's mean user scroll to **982px** at **2514ms** (origin 0 when user access the website); **1023px** at **2588ms**, ......

[image]

So I want to calculate how long user **stop at specific point**, example 1000px

Please note that user maybe scroll from TOP to BOTTOM, then BOTTOM to TOP

thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with "example 1000px"?? the sum of the times corresponding to the numbers of the first array smaller than 1000?

Comment: @Berto99 If user scroll to 800px at time 1500ms, and to 1500px at time 3500ms, that's mean (may be!) user stop at 1000px in (3500 - 1500) = 2000ms. And we must consider if user have scrolled from BOTTOM to TOP too

Comment: and in which language you want this?

Comment: Careful, you're using a set for the scroll position. If the value stops twice at the same pixel value, everything will be wrong because a set can only contain once each value (for example if the value goes back to 982px, it won't be added). Use an array instead (`[int, int, ...]`). For timestamp it doesn't matter because the score keeps incrementing. (Python ?)

Comment: @ErnestBidouille Sorry, I mean ARRAY, it's just array in Golang output. I've edited my question

Comment: You are asking "how long user stop at specific point, example 1000px?" If you take first two elements positions as 982, 1023 and times as 2514, 2588, the position 1000 exists between 982, 1023 now how long at 1000 how do you know? maybe a milli second? It depends on scroll speed. Lets say scroll speed is uniform that we can calculate by (d2-d1)/(t2-t1) even then you can say at what time do you reach 1000 and not something like how much time you are at the point right?

Comment: @SomeDude Yes, absolutely right. And I don't known other better solution to resolve this problem. It's very complicated

Comment: @SomeDude The scroll speed can detect by the time that user stop at every points

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript could be something like this, if you want it in other language it's just matter of language syntactic:

```js
/*
   positions: array of positions
   times: array with the moments user stop ad each position
   p: interested position
   return: probabile time user stops at p (or saw p)
*/
function(positions, times, p){
    var tot = 0;
    if(position[0]>p) tot+= times[0]; // first position already greater than the desired once 
    for(var i = 1; i < positions.length; i++){
        if(
             Math.min(positions[i-1], positions[i]) < p // greater then the smaller position between the current 2
             && 
             Math.max(positions[i-1], positions[i]) > p// smaller then the grater position between the current 2
                 ) tot+= times[i] - times[i-1];
    }
    return tot;
}
```

Comment: I've created a sandbox of your answer, let's discus
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mcclintock-1jxu1

Comment: Your solution is wrong, please check 1700 in sandbox

Comment: which output are you looking for that value?

Comment: Please update sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-frost-5129t, check time at 1625px and 1731px, Please note that user also scroll from TOP => BOTTOM and then BOTTOM => TOP

Comment: @Enesy yes, of course, but there is also "1750,1661" at the end of the list, so the user was scrolling up from 1750 to 1661

Comment: Sorry, I'v confirmed that's your solution is right.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, but not sure it resolved.
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-frost-5129t